# convert webServes type variable with local variable

Tags: c#

I have a C# project, I take date from DB with web service, I have the same classes in webService and C# project, class Artikels. From webService I return a list of this class Artikel in my C# project, this is the code:

List listArt = webService.Artikels().ToList();
/* now in listArt I have all artikel from webService, I must to convert this list in my local list class type ex:*/
List localList = listArt; // this retur me an error:Cannot implicitly convert type

there are a posibility to convert my local list class with the list class from my webService another to parse each element??
thank you

Comment: The Artikels in your webService isn't the same class as your project class Artikels is it? i.e. are the classes defined twice, and each with their own namespace? If you can just use the webService version of the class in your project then you won't need to reflect into a different class.

Comment: Thank you for message. I now, but I have a big project and better is to use my C# variable, for this I must to have existing variable. How the project work with the serialise and desearlise function

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Where does your Artikels class come from? It sounds like you have it defined in your service *and* in your consuming project. This is why you get the 'cannot implicitly convert type' message, because it is trying to convert a `webservice.artikels` class into a `local.artikels` class. Just use the webservice version of the class, if you can, because your consuming project already knows about it.